# Singular ID request returning an array of all Id's in .netcore MVC

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, razor, bootstrap-4

In my loop I'm creating a table from the model with a loop but when I use my delete function it returns back an array of all ID's instead of the singular clicked.

```
<tbody id="itemTable">
                @foreach (var item in Model.tableItems)
                { 
                <tr>
                    <td id="idRow">@item.ID</td>  
                    <td>@item.MemberName</td>
                    <td>@item.Details</td>
                    <td>@item.StatusDesc</td>
                    <td class="justify-content-center">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#notesModal-@item.ID">
                            <i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
                        </button>
                        
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="showDeleteModalBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal-@item.ID" data-show="true">
                            <i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-2x "></i>
                        </button>

                        <!---------------------- DELETE MODAL------------------------------------------>
                        <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal-@item.ID" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">

                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h3 class="modal-title" id="titleLabel">Are you Sure?</h3>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div>@item.ID</div>
```

> **where I am assigning the ID**

```
                                    <input type="hidden" name="ID" id="itemID-@item.ID" value="@item.ID" asp-for="ID" />
                                    <label class="form-text text-muted">Delete for @item.MemberName ?</label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete<i class="fas fa-trash-alt ml-2"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            }
```

And here is what its returning.
[image: The Request Payload]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: My Form was submitting all I had to re arrange the form to submit only the model in the loop instead of capturing all.

```
 <tbody id="dissatTable">
                @foreach (DissatisfactionTableModel item in Model.tableItems)
                {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.ID</td>
                    <td>@item.MemberName</td>
                    <td>@item.Details</td>
                    <td>@item.StatusDesc</td>
                    <td class="justify-content-center">
                        <form action="/Dissatisfactions/DeleteDissat" method="post">

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#notesModal">
                                <i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="showDeleteModalBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal-@item.ID" data-show="true">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-2x "></i>
                            </button>

                            <!---------------------- DELETE MODAL------------------------------------------>
                            <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal-@item.ID" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

                                    <div class="modal-content">

                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h3 class="modal-title" id="titleLabel">Are you Sure?</h3>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <input id="dissatID" type="text" name="ID" value="@item.ID" asp-for="ID" />
                                            <label class="form-text text-muted">Delete Dissat for @item.MemberName ?</label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="">Delete<i class="fas fa-trash-alt ml-2"></i></button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because your modal is inside the for loop?